# LLM Model train

Tags: nlp, large-language-model

I want to develop a language model myself. I want to use a pre-trained model for this. I don't want to have any commercial connection, I want to use it to develop the model and direct it the way I want. Is there a service that provides this or is there any document or video that can guide me on this? The LLM models all have strict licenses not to use them in certain areas. So I don't want to have any contact with anyone after I develop the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no need to invent the wheel yourself. Training (or even fine-tuning) a language model can be tricky and sometimes impractical for non-experienced users.

Your problem can be solved a lot easier. There are also platforms like [local-GPT](https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT) with your concern in mind.

Also, not all models have strict licensing issues. Just take a look at [here](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text-generation&sort=trending). You can see that there are lots of models that have MIT and Apache licenses.